# Calculate dashed progress path in SVG circle

Tags: css, svg

I'm building a progress circle that represents a users level up to three. It contains three dashes around the perimeter. A darker line that overlaps each dash will represent the user's progress. If a user is level one, the first dash should be overlapped by an amount equal to (their current experience / total experience to next level). If the user  is level two, the first dash should be fully overlapped and the second dash should be the same as the above and so on. I've built my SVG circle with the following code:

```
<svg
   width="240"
   height="240"
   viewBox="0 0 240 240"
   strokeWidth="2px"
   strokeDasharray="220 10"
   strokeDashoffset="50"
>
    <circle cx="120" cy="120" r="110" fill="white" stroke="turquoise" />
</svg>
```

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XewWd.png) represents a  user that is on level two and about halfway through to level three.

How could I calculate a `<path>` to overlap the circle and display the user's progress?

Comment: Don't. Use multiple circles. Simpler all round.

Comment: I've dabbled with it here, which requires four elements and some JS: https://jsfiddle.net/76ho3bgr/

Comment: Since you didn't suggest any JS to be used, I won't post an answer. But I've been playing around a bit if it's of any interest - if you change the variable `status` at the top between 0 and 3 it will animate the path offsets to that level subsequently with constant speed: https://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/bGRwawv

Comment: @Shikkediel This is great! I should've specified that using JS is absolutely no problem. This is being included inside a React project so I'm trying my best to remove the jQuery references and "React-ify" the code wherever I can. Question for you- how can I remove the hooks at the ends of each path?

Comment: Could you maybe specify what you mean with hooks exactly? I suppose you are referring to the event listeners that make the animation sequential but I'm not familiar with React jargon.

Comment: @Shikkediel Sorry that wasn't very clear. I am referring to literal hooks in the paths that make up the circle. Increasing the stroke width on `#level path:first-child` makes it more clear what I'm referring to. [Here's an image](https://i.imgur.com/KliMOCq.png) as well so you can see what I mean. I would like those lines to ideally have a round cap like you can see in the original image I shared up top.

Comment: Okay, solved that... hadn't noticed it before. Seemed very odd but was caused by the overlap of `fill: white` on mutliple elements.

Comment: @Shikkediel Looking perfect now! Huge thanks to you for your help and interest in this little problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd do it with an arc path. Draw the arc from the bottom of the circle to +1 unit in the x axis. Set the pathLength="100" so you can calculate the required dash array appropriately. Then make sure your dash-array adds up to 100.

Note - you can't use a round line-cap for this method - there is a bug in Chrome that adds an incorrect line-cap at the end of the stroke-dash array.

```html
<svg
   width="240px"
   height="240px"
   viewBox="0 0 240 240"
   stroke-width="4"
   stroke-dasharray="220 10"
   stroke-dashoffset="50"
   stroke-linecap ="none">
  
    <circle cx="120" cy="120" r="110" fill="white" stroke="turquoise" />
    <path pathLength="100" d="M120 230 a 110 110 0 1 1 1 0" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="0 1 32 1 15 50" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can control the length of each path by setting the `stroke-dasharray`. The first number is the length (between 0 and 94 (2*PI*45/3 = 94)) and the second number is the space between strokes (this should just be more than 284).

In this example the red path is 50% length. You need to experiment a bit with the numbers.

```js
var dist = 6;
console.log('Length of 1/3 circle:', Math.round(2 * Math.PI * 45 / 3)-dist);
console.log('Rotate <g> slightly:',-Math.round(2 * Math.PI * 45 / 12)-(dist/2));
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300" height="300">
      <g transform="translate(50 50) rotate(-27)">
         <path transform="rotate(0)" d="M 45,0 A 45,45 0 0 1 0,45 45,45 0 0 1 -45,0 45,45 0 0 1 0,-45 45,45 0 0 1 45,0 Z" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="44 400" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
         <path transform="rotate(120)" d="M 45,0 A 45,45 0 0 1 0,45 45,45 0 0 1 -45,0 45,45 0 0 1 0,-45 45,45 0 0 1 45,0 Z" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="88 400" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="navy" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
         <path transform="rotate(240)" d="M 45,0 A 45,45 0 0 1 0,45 45,45 0 0 1 -45,0 45,45 0 0 1 0,-45 45,45 0 0 1 45,0 Z" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="88 400" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="orange" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I question your design for readability:

[image]

This design is based on Google Analystics graphs:

[image]

- [Dev To Blogpost on how to built Graphs with Web Components](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56)
- [Web Component source: https://progress-circle.github.io/element.js](https://github.com/progress-circle/progress-circle.github.io/blob/main/element.js):
- All HTML Required:

```html
<script src="https://progress-circle.github.io/element.js"></script>

    <progress-circle edge="grey">
      <style>
        svg {
          font: 16px arial;
          height: 180px;
        }
      </style>
      <progress value="75%" stroke="green">Level I</progress>
      <progress value="60%" stroke="orange">Level II</progress>
      <progress value="50%" stroke="orangered">Level III</progress>
    </progress-circle>
```